# Find out gradient of electric potential at ${\bf r}$ created by eletric dipole of moment ${\bf p}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, multipole-expansion, dipole-moment

Suposing an electric dipole of moment ${\bf p}$ located at the origin which creates an electric potential at ${\bf r}$ given by $$\psi(\textbf{r})=\frac{\textbf{p}\centerdot\textbf{r}}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^3}$$
where the bold letters represent vectors. Find the electric field  $\textbf{E}=-\nabla\psi$
solution is supposed to be

$$\textbf{E}=\frac{3\textbf{û}(\textbf{p}\centerdot\textbf{û})-\textbf{p}}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^3}$$

with $$\textbf{û}=\frac{\textbf{r}}{r}$$

the unit vector in the direction of **r**
i've been trying to solve this for couple hours and i'm missing something when trying to solve 
$$\nabla\psi(\frac{\textbf{p}\centerdot\textbf{r}}{r^3})=\nabla\psi(\frac{\textbf{p}\centerdot\textbf{û}}{r^2})$$

more specifically I tried using the quotient rule for that gradient resulting in

$$\frac{\nabla(\textbf{p}\centerdot\textbf{û})r^2-(\textbf{p}\centerdot\textbf{û})\nabla(r^2)}{r^4}$$

where the first gradient becomes $\frac{\textbf{p}}{r}$ by use of the gradient of dot product identity and recalling that curl of **û** is 0 and every term that differentiates **p** is also 0 as **p** is a constant vector.

Comment: Please have a look at [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and also note that you did not ask a question (at least that I see).

Comment: About the homework policy this isn't a homework but rather a question i came across while reading a book on mathematical methods for physicists so it didn't seem to me that it was an invalid question though maybe more mathematical than physics. Trying to be more specific my trouble there is about how to apply a gradient over a function that is composed of one which has a product of vectors and another (quotient) with both dependending indirectly of x,y,z. I can remove the question if you still feel it's not a valid question. Thanks for the reply btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the fact that
$$
\vec \nabla(\vec p \cdot \vec r)=\vec p
$$
and
$$
\vec \nabla (r^{-3})=-3r^{-4}\vec \nabla r
$$
and
$$
\vec \nabla r = \vec r/r 
$$

Comment: Thanks i managed to solve using your relations. I was miss calculating a chain rule there. If i may ask though, isn't $\vec p \centerdot \vec r = r(\vec p \centerdot \hat{\textbf{r}})$ ? then why does $$\nabla (\frac{\vec p \centerdot \hat{\textbf{r}}}{r^2}) = \frac{p-2\hat{\textbf{r}}(\vec p \centerdot \hat{\textbf{r}})}{r^3} \neq \nabla (\frac{\vec p \centerdot \vec r}{r^3})$$

Comment: Because you messed up the calculation going from the far left-hand-side across the first equal sign.

Comment: I've been trying but i can't see where i missed.
$\begin{eqnarray*}
\nabla[(\vec{p} \cdot \hat{\textbf{r}})r^{-2}]&=&r^{-2}\nabla(\vec{p} \cdot \hat{\textbf{r}})+(\vec{p} \cdot \hat{\textbf{r}})\nabla(r^{-2})\\
&=&r^{-2}[(\vec{p} \cdot \nabla)\hat{\textbf{r}}+(\hat{\textbf{r}} \cdot \nabla)\vec{p}+\vec{p} \times(\nabla \times \hat{\textbf{r}})+\hat{\textbf{r}} \times(\nabla \times \vec{p})]-2r^{-3}(\vec{p} \cdot \hat{\textbf{r}})\nabla r\\
&=&\frac{\vec{p}-2 \hat{\textbf{r}}(\vec{p} \cdot \hat{\textbf{r}})}{r^3}
\end{eqnarray*}$  
sorry for all the trouble but i really can't see where i missed